# Android, NDK, Audio routing, forcing audio through the headset

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-source, android-audiorecord

### Use-case

- Record Android Headset audio

### Environment

- Samsung Galaxy 5
- Android 5.0
- Windows Desktop OS w/ a USB audio capture device

### Implementation

- Hook the Android device headset output to the Windows OS Line-In input
- Record whatever is sent out from the Android Device

### Problem statement

- If plugging in the Audio jack while audio is playing on the Android device the device audio output is routed through the headset jack and recording works properly
- Once audio playback ( for eg. a song ) has stopped on the Android device, the next time it'll start audio playback will use the device speaker rather than the headset jack ( used for recording )

### Attempted Problem resolution

- A native C++ command line tool running under the shell account ( can't use Java for this )
- dynamically load 'libmedia.so' and call eg. [android::AudioSystem::setForceUse](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/media/libmedia/AudioSystem.cpp)(AUDIO_POLICY_FORCE_FOR_MEDIA, AUDIO_POLICY_FORCE_HEADPHONES)
- logcat reports:

  - 02-26 10:39:50.418 289 1707 ServiceManager Permission failure: android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS from uid=2000 pid=19577
  - 02-26 10:39:50.418 289 1707  Request requires android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS

### Questions

- Having in mind that the solution should run on a non-rooted device

  - Is there a way to grant the 'android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS' permission to the 'shell' account?
  - Is there any other way to force **system wide**( and not app specific ) audio through the headset ?

### Code snap

```
            HRESULT forceAudioThroughHeadPhones() {
                typedef int(*SET_FORCE_USE)(audio_policy_force_use_t usage, audio_policy_forced_cfg_t config);
                struct sigaction sa, osa;
                sa.sa_flags = SA_ONSTACK | SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO;
                sa.sa_sigaction = [](int signo, siginfo_t* psi, void *data)->void { ucontext_t *uc = (ucontext_t *)data; };
                sigaction(SIGILL, &sa, &osa);
                void* hMod = dlopen("libmedia.so", RTLD_LAZY);
                sigaction(SIGILL, &osa, 0);
                if (0 == hMod)
                    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND);
                SET_FORCE_USE setForceUse = (SET_FORCE_USE)dlsym(hMod, "_ZN7android11AudioSystem11setForceUseE24audio_policy_force_use_t25audio_policy_forced_cfg_t");
                if (0 == setForceUse)
                    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND);
                android::status_t err;
                if (ERROR_SUCCESS != (err = setForceUse(AUDIO_POLICY_FORCE_FOR_MEDIA, AUDIO_POLICY_FORCE_HEADPHONES)))
                    return E_FAIL;
                if (ERROR_SUCCESS != (err = setForceUse(AUDIO_POLICY_FORCE_FOR_SYSTEM, AUDIO_POLICY_FORCE_HEADPHONES)))
                    return E_FAIL;
                return S_OK;
            }
```

- 'setForceUse' returns -1, errno equals to 'Zero'.

### UPDATE:

I get the same permission logcat errors when using *adb shell service call ...*:

```
10|shell@klte:/ $ service call media.audio_policy 1 i32 2 
Result: Parcel(ffffffff    '....')
```

Comment: This is a very surprising problem report.  How would an ordinary user listen to music on headphones with this device?  Or is the problem confined to the audio output of a specific application, which is perhaps *designed* to intentionally use the speaker rather than headphones?

Comment: This is not specific to an application, For example: it happens with the built-in 'Music' application ( used to play the music play-lists ), and thus, while a song is playing it properly is sent to the headset, when one song switch to the next audio revert to the speaker. BIG NOTE: when using the Headset provided w/ the phone, audio DOESN'T fall-back to the speaker, this happen ONLY when connecting the device to the 'Line-in' socket of my Win8 PC, mayB it's due to the connection impedance I don't know, still, have to figure-out a workaround

Comment: Okay, that it works with stock headphones changes things, and makes it seem more like the detection mechanism than a bug.  Try putting 32 ohm resistors across each speaker channel, to simulate the load of a high impedance headphone.  You should probably also couple the audio to the input through a .1uF or 1uF non-polarized capacitor (though the input may already have one, it is better to provide your own).