# Media Recorder To record calls is sometime unable to Record other side voice

Tags: android, phone-call, android-mediarecorder, android-phone-call

In my application there is a feature to record voice calls and it works perfectly well. But when tested on (Samsung s7, s8 ) it doesn’t work well. The application is able to record only callers voice not the voice from the other end. Below is my code to check please suggest a solution

```
MediaRecd = new MediaRecorder();
            MediaRecd.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL
            );

            MediaRecd.setAudioChannels(ConstantVariables.audioChannels);//monoRecording

   MediaRecd.setAudioEncodingBitRate(64);
            MediaRecd.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);


            MediaRecd.setOutputFormat(output_formats[pos]);//.mp3
            MediaRecd.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);//I already try with all possible CAMCORDER , MIC , Default etc etc but none was working
            MediaRecd.setOutputFile(Currentfilename);

            try {
                MediaRecd.prepare();
                MediaRecd.start();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                MediaRecd.reset();
                MediaRecd.release();
                MediaRecd = null;

            }
```

Please help

Comment: Same on my end...

Comment: what solution you tried for this? currently i stuck in this problem.

Comment: On which OS version it is not working?

Comment: both S7 and S8 have OS 7 version

Comment: tried to use my below answer approach and update.

Comment: No bro its not working i already did this but S7 and S8 didnt get other side voice.

Comment: check on other manufacture with same OS

Comment: I checked with Samsung S6 edge with OS 7 and it working perfectly and also I check with Nexus 6p OS 7 also its working perfectly

Comment: try these two also VOICE_DOWNLINK and VOICE_UPLINK.
Ideally you should keep all the sources in an array and try each of them out one during some kind of a setup and ask the user which one works. then choose the one that the user approved.

Comment: @Manas Dadheech I already did with all the Methods from Media Recorder class and audio Recorder class but i think this is something else which I can't found yet.

Comment: @BhanuSharma i am also stuck with the same problem , i am also having S7 edge... were you able to resolve this issue? lets discuss over chat?

Comment: @japanjotsingh i still stuck in same

Comment: @BhanuSharma Did you find the solution?

Comment: No still not found..

Comment: Hi BhanuSharma, I am also trying to record incoming and outgoing calls but unable to record. I am working on it from 2 days but it is not working.I am using MediaRecorder when ever call started but not working.Please help me on this.

Comment: @Naveen Have u got success on any mobile because in my case I failed on Samsung S7 and more of its successor. My prob was I was not able to record other side's voice in some mobile, not each

Comment: Hi Bhanu Sharma, I cannot able to record the voice on the other side in all cases.Actually I have tried the code in Lollipop(Below Marshmallow), Pie(Above Marshmallow).It failed in all the cases.Can you help me on this please ?

Comment: @BhanuSharma VOICE_CALL permission is only for system apps, did you check?

Answer (score -1):

`AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` is not working in some android devices so
instead of `VOICE_CALL` use below

First try `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER`

```
 MediaRecd = new MediaRecorder();
        MediaRecd.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER
        );
```

If above is not working than use `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC`

```
MediaRecd = new MediaRecorder();
        MediaRecd.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC
        );
```

Comment: NO its not working  @Vishal I already did this think but Samsung S7 and S8 doesn't work from these